# Почему один и тот же regexp работает в онлайн тестере и не работает в PHP

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Не могу понять почему так происходит

```
исходная строка:
$data = "structure.declination(123, результат, результата, результатов)"
regexp:
preg_match_all("/([A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*[_]*)+[.]([A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*[_]*)+[(]([A-Z]*[А-я]*[a-z]*[0-9]*[%@':\-.|<,>*#\/_ ]*)+([%]..+[%])*[)]/", $data, $mass);
```

в php не проходит проверку т.е. $mass пустой, а тестирую на gskinner.com/RegExr/ все работает

причем, если заменить русские буквы  на английские и убрать условие, которое я добавил [А-я], то все работает прекрасно, но суть в том чтобы работало вместе с русскими буквами

Comment: такой вопрос: что вы хотите получить? может быть мы вам подскажем более простую регулярку. И вам опыт и нам хорошо. По теме: не могу запустить регулярку, всё перепробовал, результатов 0.

Comment: есть макросы вида %structure.name(param1, param2, parm3)% - макрос функция и вида %count% - макрос значение

текущая регулярка работает на английских буквах т.е. в param можно передавать практически все (кроме русских букв), мне нужно чтобы в параметры можно было и русские буквы передавать как в примере, система определяет является ли это макросом по регулярке, дальше идет разбор на параметры и тд и тп, но поддержку русских букв не получается добваить, хотя по логике вроде бы правильно

Answer (score 3):

```
$data = "structure.declination(123, русский, чочочо, mamamia)";

preg_match_all("/(\w*)\.(\w*)\((.*?)\)/", $data, $mass);

var_dump($mass);

array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(52) "structure.declination(123, русский, чочочо, mamamia)"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "structure"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "declination"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(29) "123, русский, чочочо, mamamia"
  }
}
```

Если я правильно понял.

Comment: Спасибо, но не совсем)) макрос нужен в целом без частей, сам разбор макроса идет дальше.

Но вообщем тут нашли уже ответ, ларчик как всегда просто открывался,
в конце регулярки нужно было поставить /u 
PS как же меня бесят все эти кодировки >_<

Comment: ну да, либо модификатор "u" можно было подставить :-) Еще можно упростить конструкцию ([A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*[_]*) в ([a-z0-9-_]*) + добавить модификатор "i"

Answer (score 0):

Не пишите отдельно символы, которые могут идти вперемежку. Также используйте модификатор i, чтобы не перечислять все возможные регистры символов.
У меня работает вот этот шаблон для вашей ситуации:

```
preg_match_all("/([a-z0-9_.]*)+\(([a-za-я0-9%@':\-.|<,>*#\/_ ]*)\)/i", $data, $mass);
```